Trying to replace the letters of a word to underscore
So as the title gives away, I wanna replace the letters of a word (That you input) to underscore ( _ ) or atleast to something different.
Now I have made a topic about this before and got some help, but I couldn't figure out how to apply it to my code. So with his help and we both agreed it would be best if I made a new topic and also translated my code (Originally I am Dutch so) for better clarity.
So in the section "class ChooseMain(tk.Frame):" I have a user input a word that will be the word to guess.
The code in question for the input is:
self.woordEntry = tk.Entry(self, textvariable=self.controller.shared_data["chosenWord"])

Which in turn is sent to the next class called "ChosenMain" through this code:
btnContinue = tk.Button(self, text="Continue", command=lambda: controller.show_frame("ChosenMain"))

Now in the next class ("ChosenMain" in this case) it will show 3 things. 1 is word that was inputted on the previous screen and 2 buttons.
The word that was put in is displayed like this:
wordLabel = tk.Label(self, textvariable=self.controller.shared_data["chosenWord"], font=("futura"))
wordLabel.pack(side="top")

Now this shows the word that was input as normal but obviously I don't want to show it as normal, preferably as _ _ _ _ or something similar. And that is where I am stuck.
Now as mentioned I did get help before this which was here: Trying to replace label text to underscore for a game of hangman
As mentioned there, I tried the solutions posted there but I just couldn't get the wordLabel section to be changed to _ or * or anything really.
I'll post my full code below this, and I hope I didn't forget to translate something. Again if there is more information required or whatever. Feel free to comment here or message me and I will try my best to help!
#Hangman

import tkinter as tk

class Hangman(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        self.shared_data = {
            "chosenWord": tk.StringVar()
        }

        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, minsize=500,  weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, minsize=600, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}

        for F in (ChooseMain, ChosenMain):
            page_name = F.__name__
            frame = F(parent=container, controller=self)
            self.frames[page_name] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame("ChooseMain")

    def show_frame(self, page_name):
        for frame in self.frames.values():
            frame.grid_remove()
        frame = self.frames[page_name]
        frame.grid()

class ChooseMain(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller

        label = tk.Label(self, text="Choose your word")
        label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady="10")
        self.wordEntry = tk.Entry(self, textvariable=self.controller.shared_data["chosenWord"])
        self.wordEntry.pack(pady=10)

        btnContinue = tk.Button(self, text="Continue", command=lambda: controller.show_frame("ChosenMain"))
        btnContinue.pack()


class ChosenMain(tk.Frame):    
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Guess the word!")
        label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)

        wordLabel = tk.Label(self, textvariable=self.controller.shared_data["chosenWord"], font=("futura"))
        
        wordLabel.pack(side="top")

        self.wentry = tk.Entry(self)
        self.wentry.pack(pady=10)
        GuessButton = tk.Button(self, text="Guess!", command=self.GuessWord)
        GuessButton.pack()
        NewWoord = tk.Button(self, text="Choose different word", command=self.ChangeWord)
        NewWoord.pack()

    def GuessWord(self):
        return True
        
    def ChangeWord(self):
        self.refresh()
        self.controller.show_frame("ChooseMain")

    def refresh(self):
        self.wentry.delete(0, "end")
        #self.text.delete("1.0", "end")
        self.wentry.focus_set()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    galgbord = Hangman()
    galgbord.mainloop()


I don't see anywhere in this code where you actually try to change the letters to underscores.  Where, exactly, did you expect that to happen?

self.controller.shared_data["chosenWord"] is a tk.StringVar which means you have to use its method get to retrieve the entered string, create a modified string according to the answer you already got and then use set method to write it back to the variable (and therefore automatically to the label).

@JohnGordon I removed those from my code as they were only giving errors, but I tried a few methods like labelTest = tk.Label(self) labelTest.config(textvariable=controller.shared_data["gekozenWoord"].get()) and then print labelTest but yeah that doesn't seem to work. Can't really seem to wrap my head around it.

@MichaelButscher As my comment towards John Gordon, I do try to get some .get shenanigangs but I can't seem to find where to place it or how to write the code to make it effective and work. Can't seem to wrap my head around it.

With word = self.controller.shared_data["chosenWord"].get() you assign the string content of the variable to word. Then you create the desired underscore string and assign it to word and finally you execute self.controller.shared_data["chosenWord"].set(word).

@MichaelButscher So I added this to the ChosenMain class:
    underscoreWord = self.controller.shared_data["gekozenWoord"].get()
    underscoredWord = "- " * len(underscoreWord)

    showWord = self.controller.shared_data["gekozenWoord"].set(underscoredWord)
    Words = tk.Label(text=showWord)
    Words.pack(side="bottom")

And although no error shows up. It also doesn't show anything else that's different. So I feel like I'm missing something.

Why did you add the lines Words = tk.Label(text=showWord) and Words.pack(side="bottom")? They are neither in the original code nor in my comment.

@MichaelButscher Oh I know, I added this myself cause I wanted to see if I needed that to get the word to show up. I have a label already on the ChosenMain class that shows the word that I inputted in the previous screen, but I can't get that one to change to underscore or * or whatever.

As you create both frames on application start, you must inform frame ChosenMain when it really becomes visible and then execute the conversion code. This can be done with the Visibility event like so:
class ChosenMain(tk.Frame):    
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller

        self.bind("<Visibility>", self.visible)  # <-- Bind method to event

        label = tk.Label(self, text="Guess the word!")
        label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)

        wordLabel = tk.Label(self, textvariable=self.controller.shared_data["chosenWord"], font=("futura"))
        
        wordLabel.pack(side="top")

        self.wentry = tk.Entry(self)
        self.wentry.pack(pady=10)
        GuessButton = tk.Button(self, text="Guess!", command=self.GuessWord)
        GuessButton.pack()
        NewWoord = tk.Button(self, text="Choose different word", command=self.ChangeWord)
        NewWoord.pack()

    # Method to be called when frame becomes visible
    def visible(self, _):
        underscoreWord = self.controller.shared_data["chosenWord"].get()
        underscoredWord = "- " * len(underscoreWord)
        self.controller.shared_data["chosenWord"].set(underscoredWord)
 


A simple way to create a string with underscores and the same length than a given word is:
underscored_word = "_" * len(my_word)

